# Running a 1 time task to enter values into database in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have now added a new column to my table in database. I want to add some values to some rows in this new column. I know the logic and all. But actually I dont know the way to add this, or write a 1 time task to do this in ruby on rails. Can any one help me. I just need some idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a rake task for this, and run it once.

Create a file `lib/tasks/my_namespace.rake`

```
namespace :my_namespace do
  desc "My Task description"
  task :my_task => :environment do
    # Code to make db change goes here
  end
end
```

You can invoke the task from the command line in project root folder like

`rake my_namespace:my_task RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: @NidhinSG, no extra gem is required for this

Answer (score 2):

```
data = Model.where(#your_condition)
```

if the value is same for all

```
data.update_all(:new_column => "new value")
```

if the value is different for all

```
data.each do |d|
  d.update_attributes(:new_column => "some value")
end
```

Comment: how to run this as 1 time task?