# how to run a one-time database change on a single user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have Customer and each customer has_many Properties. Customers belong to a Company.

I'm trying to add a certain Property to each one of a single Company's Customers. I only want this change to happen once.

I'm thinking about using a migration but it doesn't seem right to create a migration for a change that I only ever want to happen once, and only on one of my users.

Is there a right way to do this?

Comment: rails console? rake task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a 1 time task to enter values into database in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959356/running-a-1-time-task-to-enter-values-into-database-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use rails console.
In rails c:

```
Company.where(conditions).last.customers.each do |customer|
  customer.properties << Property.where(condition)
  customer.save!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Validation**

Depending on how you're changing the `Customer` model, I'd include a simple vaidation on the [`before_update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback to see if the attribute is populated or not:

```
#app/models/Customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_update :is_valid?
   private

   def is_valid?
      return if self.attribute.present?
   end

end
```

This will basically check if the model has the attribute populated. If it does, it means you'll then be able to `update` it, else it will break

--

**Strong_Params**

An alternative will be to set the [`strong_params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) so that the attribute you want to remain constant will not be changed when you update / create the element:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   ...

   private

   def strong_params
      params.require(:model).permit(:only, :attributes, :to, :update)
   end
end
```

---

It would be much more helpful if you explained the context as to why you need this type of functionality - that will give people the ability to create a real solution, instead of proposing ideas